# Select specific rows in SQLite query?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to understand what's the best way to get specific rows out of a table in one query.

Let's say my table columns are:

Name, age, country

Let's say it has 1000 rows. I then have an array of indexes that represent the rows:

[2,10,20,34,50,120,400, 410,444,810]

How can I get the corresponding names? So, [name at row 2, name at row 10, ....]

I saw something like this online:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` IN (5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

but, I don't have an id column...do I need to manipulate the table or DB before pulling something like that off?

Comment: A table itself is an unordered set of rows. If you say you have indexes like 2, 10, and so on, what do they refer to? You say there is no ID in the table? So maybe ist another column? One called `index` maybe? Or are your index numbers just the row numbers according to some order? Which order then? Is there a date column or something you order by?

Comment: Seems like you are using something more than just SQLite. Might be a good idea to mention what it is, since you write about array of indexes used for row representation. How do you construct such array?

Comment: so, I do some work with other queries in sqlite on the table, then part of my logic is to keep track of indexes as I loop through previous queries... that's where my "indexes" are coming from... does it make sense?

Comment: But so far you are kind of saying you have a pot of peas and you want peas number 2, 10, 20, … How is anybody to know which is pea #2? Ho do you get these numbers? They don't seem to have any meaning.

Comment: I don't see why you would need an array of indices then. It might be better to ask a question providing an example of what it is you have and try to achieve instead of a general one. Right now I don't feel informed enough to post any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would work (to a fashion) :-

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE rowid IN (5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

This is because generally the ubiquitous **id** column is generally an alias of the special (normally hidden) **rowid** column.

That is a table that is not defined using **WITHOUT ROWID** will have a **rowid** column with automatically generated id's (unless the rowid is specified or implicitly specified via a column that is an alias of the **rowid** column).

An alias of the **rowid** column is defined by specifying **`?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`** (where ?? represents a valid column name (often id)). The keyword **`AUTOINCREMENT`** can compliment `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and it adds a constraint that the generated **id** (i.e. the **rowid**) **MUST** increase, *whilst without unused lower numbers can be used (only relevant when the highest id is 9223372036854775807)*. With **`AUTOINCREMENT`**, should this highest id be reached then an SQLITE_FULL exception will be encountered (without an attempt will be made to select a lower free number first).

The above is a summary of some of the points from [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

#### Example Demonstration

Consider the following (the last two SELECT queries being the equivalent of the answer) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rowid_demo1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rowid_demo2;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rowid_demo1 (name TEXT, age INTEGER, country TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rowid_demo2 (id_column INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, age INTEGER, country TEXT);
INSERT INTO rowid_demo1 (name,age,country) VALUES
    ('Fred',22,'England'),('Mary',18,'Scotland'),('Heather',19,'Wales');
INSERT INTO rowid_demo2 (name,age,country) VALUES
    ('Fred',22,'England'),('Mary',18,'Scotland'),('Heather',19,'Wales');

SELECT *,rowid as rowid_column FROM rowid_demo1;
SELECT *,rowid as rowid_column FROM rowid_demo2;
INSERT INTO rowid_demo1 (rowid,name,age,country) VALUES
    (100,'George',21,'France');
INSERT INTO rowid_demo2 (rowid,name,age,country) VALUES
    (100,'George',21,'France');
SELECT *,rowid as rowid_column FROM rowid_demo1;
SELECT *,rowid as rowid_column FROM rowid_demo2;
-- Ridiculous to do the following but ??????
INSERT INTO rowid_demo2 (rowid,id_column,name,age,country) VALUES
    (500,501,'Beth',20,'Spain');
SELECT *,rowid as rowid_column FROM rowid_demo1;
SELECT *,rowid as rowid_column FROM rowid_demo2;

SELECT *,rowid AS rowid_column FROM rowid_demo1 WHERE rowid IN(2,3,100);
SELECT *,rowid AS rowid_column FROM rowid_demo2 WHERE rowid IN(2,3,100,501);
```

#### Explanation

This :-

- creates 2 tables (the same other than rowid_demo2 has an alias of the rowid column) and - loads some data
- runs 2 SELECT queries (one for each table) to shows the rows including the **rowid** column. (results 1 and 2)
- some more data is loaded. However, this time by specifying values for the **rowid**
- The same 2 queries are run (results 3 and 4)
- a ridiculous row is added to the 2nd table (both the rowid and it's alias are given values)
- Again the same 2 queries are run (results 5 and 6)
- Queries equivalent to the answer are run (results 7 and 8).

#### Demonstration results :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll go through it and try to understand it all. It'll take me a while, I am no SQL expert, but I'll see how I can use this info to get done what I need. It looks promising.

Comment: Ok, so using the rowid column does the trick. I didn't know that column is usually hidden like you stated and so I had no core id I could use to reference the row I cared about. Now I can add the "rowid," in the SELECT part of the query and that allows me to first id the rows I need and then use what you suggested on top "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE rowid IN (5,6,7,8,9,10)". Great answer!! thank you.